# Rendering multiple datasets in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native

I want to display images and other data in scrolling container.
I have two separate apis for image & other data.
I'm using react-native flatlist. How can I render two datasets at the same time.

This is my code:

```
<FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    data={data1, data2}
    renderItem={this.renderData}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    bounces={false}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}/>

renderData = (item) => {
    <View></View>
}
```

Comment: What does `data1` and `data2` look like? How they are related? How do you fetch/get them?

Comment: data1 & data2 are two different props. I'm calling them from two different apis in componentDidMount().

Comment: What does data1 and data2 look like? How they are related?

Comment: You got to combine them into a single date set or array in this case. Then access the required data from each element of the array.

Comment: data1 & data2 are related by id.

Comment: Please show us at least the structure of your data in order for us to help

Answer (score 4):

If you want to render multiple arrays in flatlist you have to concatenate them. Change your data prop in your flatlist component to:

```
data={data1.concat(data2)}
```

I'm assuming data1 and data2 are arrays because you haven't shown what they actually are. Best case scenario here is that the 2 arrays have the same data structure just different values.

Comment: data1 & data2 have different data structure. They are related by id only.

Comment: Well you can still concatenate them, and it will work. However I'm not sure what the benefit of using two arrays with differing data structures in one flatlist would be. You might want to consider creating a new array with some logic for merging the two data sets. Or just use two different flat lists. But again, we don't know what your data looks like at all so its hard to help.

Comment: @rt_ it worked but what if I have to concat data1, data2, data3, data4, and so on.... how will I concat them all?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal You'll need to find some logic to combine these arrays. Use a loop and add them all to one.

Comment: @rt_ I tried but it didn't work as I am receiving these arrays from JSON response.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal its really hard to help you without knowing what you data looks like. I suggest you ask a new question showing what your data structures are.

Comment: Your way is very logical but its not working as @HarshitAgrawal says. Actually flatlist is not rendering itself according to new data